# On hover, I want to increase the width of the element I am hovering, but also reduce the width of 2 other elements

Tags: css, sass

I have a section which I have mocked up here: http://jsfiddle.net/josh_boothman/prry6g1r/

As you can see this is split into 3 sections which are floated and have a width of around 33.3%. What I would like to achieve is when a particular element is hovered over, say .col-one in my example, I would like that element to increase in width to 50%, whilst the remaining 2 unhovered elements would be reduced to 25% each.

```
/* SCSS */

.contact {
background: #414141;
height: 600px;
width: 90%;
margin: 0 auto;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
}

.contact-container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.contact-col {
width: calc(100% / 3);
height: 100%;
float: left;
display: inline;
@include transition(all, 0.6s);

    &:hover {
    background: rgba(248, 220, 93, 0.6);
    }
}
.contact-option {
text-align: center;
color: white;
@include vertical-align;

    h5 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 0 25px 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use multiple hovers:

```
.contact-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    &:hover {
        .contact-col {
            width: 25%;

            &:hover {
                width: 50%;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prry6g1r/3/

Comment: You forgot to save the fiddle

Comment: @cimmanon - Absolutely perfect. Thank you for your reply. I've marked your commment as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to `.contact-col`:

```
.contact-col {
  ...

  .contact-container:hover & {
    width: calc(100% / 3 / 2);

    &:hover {
      width: calc(100% / 3 * 2);
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prry6g1r/6/

The logic is that on hover of the container you reduce the width  of all the columns, but the hovered column gets an increased width, overriding the width from the container.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can't argue with that. It works great. Thanks again.